# Accessible deep UV laser

Tags: laser

An opportunity has come up to run an experiment in December that would help my project a ton. However, for this I need a specific kind of laser. I've been searching everywhere and with no success. Can someone advise me how to buy or build a laser with the following requirements?

- over 0.3 mW average power
- <500W peak power
- wavelength between 220nm and 255nm
- compact enough to bring to set up for a 1 month experiment in a lab I'm visiting
- available in two months

Comment: This is a good place to start. Use the Encyclopedia to learn about your laser, and the Buyer's Guide for find suppliers. https://www.rp-photonics.com/